# How would you use Hibernate Criteria here?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Let us state that I have a table called Tests. Each Test object has a score and I want to select Tests that are above average. Easily, one uses a Projection to get the average test score, but I would like to use it all under one Criteria rather than create a second and store the average score and reinsert it into the next Criteria.

Is something like this legal?

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Product.class);
crit.add(Expression.ge("score",Projections.avg("score")));
crit.addOrder(Order.desc("score"));
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to execute a query which selects all the products who have a score that is bigger than the average of all the scores. This needs a subquery. In HQL:

```
select product from Product product
where product.score > (select avg(product2.score) from Product product2)
```

I'll let you translate this to Criteria if you really want to do it with Criteria (which, IMHO, is a bad idea since the above is much more readable and you don't need to dynamically compose your query).